# efficiently update matrix element with a matrix of indices

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of indices I where some of the indices are repeated. I put an example below.

I have another matrix A with dimensions compatible with the indices and initiated to 0 everywhere. I would like to do something like

```
A[I] += 1
```

I face two issues:

1. `A[I] = A[I] + 1` is too inefficient
2. matrix `I` has redundant indices. For example rows 2 & 6 are identical and I would like to obtain `A[1,2] = 2`

A partial answer would be to create a 3 columns matrix with the two first columns being the product of `unique(I)` and the third column with the counts, but I don't see any solution for that either. Any pointer or help would be greatly appreciated!

```
> I is:
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    3
[4,]    1    4
[5,]    1    1
[6,]    1    2
[7,]    1    3
```

Comment: The word "index" refers to a location.  You are confusing it with the value at that location.  If `I` is a matrix, `A[I]` is highly unlikely to do what you think it does.  Please provide a small sample of `A` and what you want the updated `A` matrix to look like.

Comment: The answers below are nice. I wonder about your "too inefficient" statement.  How big are `A` and `I` ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker:  2.5e+09 matrix cells are what I am dealing with as a start and it can go bigger, because I am writing a document term matrix in text mining where each row is one document, and each column is one term in the entire vocabulary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be quickest using sparse matrix methods (see the Matrix package and others).

Using standard matricies you could collapse the identical rows using the `xtabs` function then matrix assignment (edited based on comment):

```
I <- cbind(1, c(1:4,1:3))

tmp <- as.data.frame(xtabs( ~I[,1]+I[,2] ))

A <- matrix(0, nrow=5, ncol=5)
tmp2 <- as.matrix(tmp[,1:2])
tmp3 <- as.numeric(tmp2)
dim(tmp3) <- dim(tmp2)
A[ tmp3 ] <- tmp[,3]
A
```

You could probably make it a little quicker by pulling the core functionality out of `as.data.frame.table` rather than converting to data frame and back again.

Here is another version that may be more efficient.  It will overwrite some 0's with other 0's computed by `xtabs`:

```
I <- cbind(1:5,1:5)
A <- matrix(0, 5, 5)

tmp <- xtabs( ~I[,2]+I[,1] )

A[ as.numeric(rownames(tmp)), as.numeric(colnames(tmp)) ] <- c(tmp)
A
```

If the A matrix has dimnames and the I matrix has the names instead of the indexes, then this later one will also work (just remove the `as.numeric`s.

Comment: I like the idea of using `xtabs()` but this doesn't do what it is meant to. (Look at `A` to see that). The problem is that the call to `as.numeric()` converts the character **matrix** to a numeric **vector** which completely changes the meaning of the indexing.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, can you elaborate?  My A matrix matches what I expect.  What is the difference?

Comment: Sure. Try yours with `I <- cbind(1:5, 1:5)`, for example, to see that there's a problem. Then have a look at the value of `as.numeric(as.matrix(tmp[,1:2]))` to see why. (I'm assuming you and I agree that the results of feeding `I <- cbind(1:5, 1:5)` to your code should be the 5-by-5 identity matrix.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, OK, I see the problem (did not read your comment closely enough) is that the dimensions of the matrix are dropped.  I will edit the code above with a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
## Reproducible versions of your A and I objects
A <- matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=5)
## For computations that follow, you'll be better off having this as a data.frame
## (Just use `I <- as.data.frame(I)` to convert a matrix object I).
I <- read.table(text=" 1    1
1    2
1    3
1    4
1    1
1    2
1    3", header=FALSE)

## Create data.frame with number of times each matrix element should
## be incremented
I$count <- ave(I[,1], I[,1], I[,2], FUN=length)
I <- unique(I)

## Replace desired elements, using a two column matrix (the "third form of
## indexing" mentioned in "Matrices and arrays" section" of ?"[").
A[as.matrix(I[1:2])] <- I[[3]]

A
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    2    2    2    1    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
```